# Picking order details from database in an interval

Tags: sql, date, select

I want to pull orders that have been placed in between (last 5 mins - last 10 mins). For that I am running a query:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM orders where `orderStatus`='PARTIAL' and `timeCreated` >= date_sub(now(),interval 10 minute)";
```

However, this query is picking data from between (last 0 mins - last 10 mins).

Can you please help what should I try?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

Just add another filtering condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE 
    orderStatus = 'PARTIAL' 
    AND timeCreated >= date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute)
    AND timeCreated <  date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute);
```

Assuming that you are using MySQL (the syntax of your existing query suggests it), you can also phrase the query using the following date arithmetics, which I find more straight-forward:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE 
    orderStatus = 'PARTIAL' 
    AND timeCreated >= now() - interval 10 minute
    AND timeCreated < now() - interval 5 minute
```